# Clipping of meshes when rotating

Tags: typescript, three.js, clipping

I made a model composed from some meshes in three.js but when I move my camera using OrbitControls, it seems that some of my meshes clip. Here is the render I have:

[image]

By searching on the Internet, I found some solution mentionning the `depthWrite` of the material to set to `false`. In this situation, all my elements are displayed but the 3D is broken (normal since this feature seems to be mainly designed to overlay elements in a 2D rendering). The render with the `depthWrite` disabled:

[image]

Here is a minimal example of the issue I encounter:
https://codepen.io/theogiraudet/pen/WNZKPXx?editors=0110

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `createElement` function, use this setup for material:

```js
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: createTexture(url),
    alphaTest: 0.5
  });
```

Comment: It's perfect, thanks you very much!

Comment: @Oromis You're welcome :)